# Karet for eating chametz on Pesach - Where is the line drawn?

Tags: halacha, passover, eating, chametz-leaven, karet

As I understand it, for something to count as a single act of eating, it must meet two requirements.

1. The amount ingested must be the minimum of Kezayit. Some hold this to literally be the volume of a regular olive while others hold it to be the volume of an egg (~50cc).
2. This amount must be consumed within 2 to 9 minutes (again, varying opinions).

My question is whether one earns the Karet punishment for eating chametz only while meeting these two requirements or is an even lesser amount still enough to earn Karet? For example, cooking in a not kosher for Pesach pot, or eating with not kosher for Pesach utensils and plates?

Comment: Yes you need those requirements to get karet. Its still prohibited biblicly for smaller amounts though

Comment: Would the punishment for that be flogging / lokeh?

Answer (score 1):

For a person to get a Biblically mandated punnishment, they must meet the "shiur" requirement - in this case, eat the volume of a "kzayis" of Chametz within the time span of "kdei achilas pras".

The accepted Halacha is that "chetzei shiur asur" - even eating less than this amount (or in a greater time-span) is Biblically prohibited. However, no punnishment is specified for this infraction. This means that the transgressor will not be punnished with Karet from the Heavenly court or anything from the earthly court. As with all transgressions with unspecified punnishments, there is a Heavenly punnishment but it has not been revealed.